# How to read small Data Matrix codes (16 x 16) using Python and opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, datamatrix

I can't decode the 2D data matrix using the pylibdmtx library. It is a small image (16 x 16). The result is always [ ]. Does the size of the data matrix influence decoding in this library?. Can anybody help me ?

```
from pylibdmtx.pylibdmtx import decode
import cv2
import numpy as np

image  = cv2.imread('./key1.png')
height, width = frame.shape[:2]
decode((frame.tobytes(), width, height))
```

[image]

Comment: shouldn't you use "image" instead of "frame"?

Comment: it was a mistake to paste the code. It doesn't work anyway.

Comment: The quality of the image is probably too low. It's hard to spot individual dot, try getting a better quality image and the library should be able to handle it.